# Recursion Help - Finding the maximum number of flowers seen across 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, recursion, matrix

I have a coding challenge problem that I am a little stuck on. The problem text is as follows:

> Visitors to the virtual estate are amazed at the beauty and splendor
> of your virtual gardens but are looking for guidance on the best
> places to visit to behold its magnificence.
>
> As Master Groundskeeper,
> your next task is to produce a new Text Layout of a Garden Composition
> which annotates the best locations to visit the garden with an
> asterisk (*).
>
> The best location is the Blank plot where a visitor can
> see the most flowers looking in each cardinal direction (north, south,
> east, and west). Naturally, visitors cannot see through walls. If
> there are multiple positions which can see the same number of flowers,
> your Text Layout should mark all of those positions. If there are no
> flowers in the garden, all blank plots should be marked as ideal. For
> example, given the Garden Composition

The question involves setting up a garden with flowers and walls into a 2D array, and providing a method to modify the matrix to insert an asterisk as a flag that intersects the most flowers.

B - Blank
F - Flower
W - Wall

Input:

```
B B B B B
B B F B B
B B B B B
B B F B B
B B F B B
```

Expected Output:

```
B B * B B
B B F B B - Flower 1
B B * B B
B B F B B - Flower 2
B B F B B - Flower 3

Where the two asterisks represent the only positions in the garden where a visitor 
can see 3 flowers by looking north, south, east and west
```

My initial thought was to iterate through each item in the 2D array and perform a DFS for each sequence of a Blank ("B") to obtain the number of flowers seen cardinally (i.e., north, south, east and west) of the current blank's position. I'm getting stuck where python notes that my maximum recursion depth is being exceeded and haven't been able to progress with assigning an asterisk. Any thoughts?

```
garden = [['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], ['B', 'B', 'F', 'B', 'B'], ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], ['B', 'B', 'F', 'B', 'B'], ['F', 'B', 'F', 'B', 'B']]

class Solution:
    def count(self, garden):
        maxSeenFlowers = 0

        for row in range(len(garden)):
            for col in range(len(garden[0])):
                if garden[row][col] == "B":
                    self.dfs(garden, maxSeenFlowers, row, col)
                    garden[row][col] = self.maxSeenFlowers
        print(garden)

    def dfs(self,garden,maxSeenFlowers, row, col):
        self.maxSeenFlowers = 0

        if row < 0 or col < 0 or row == len(garden) or col == len(garden[0]) or garden[row][col] == "W":
            return
        if garden[row][col] == "F":
            self.maxSeenFlowers += 1
        
        self.dfs(garden,maxSeenFlowers, row+1, col) # look to the east
        self.dfs(garden,maxSeenFlowers, row-1, col) # look to the west
        self.dfs(garden,maxSeenFlowers, row, col+1) # look to the north
        self.dfs(garden,maxSeenFlowers, row, col-1) # look to the south

    
plot1 = Solution()
plot1.count(garden)
```

EDIT: Here is the excerpt of code that I use to sum all values for each cardinal direction. Thanks @brokenbenchmark:

```
    def bestSeen(self):
    gardenScore = [[0 for i in range(len(self.garden[0]))] for j in range(len(self.garden))]
    # print(gardenScore)
    maxSeen = 0

    
    # from left to right.
    for i in range(len(self.garden)):
        row_hits = 0 
        for j in range(len(self.garden[0])):
            if self.garden[i][j] == 'F':
                row_hits += 1
            elif self.garden[i][j] == 'W':
                row_hits = 0 
            else:
                gardenScore[i][j] = row_hits 
    # print(gardenScore)

    # from right to left
    for i in range(len(self.garden)):
        row_hits = 0 
        for j in range(len(self.garden[0])-1, -1, -1):
            if self.garden[i][j] == 'F':
                row_hits += 1
            elif self.garden[i][j] == 'W':
                row_hits = 0 
            else:
                gardenScore[i][j] += row_hits 
    # print(gardenScore)

    # from bottom to top
    for i in range(len(self.garden[0])):
        col_hits = 0 
        for j in range(len(self.garden)):
            if self.garden[j][i] == 'F':
                col_hits += 1
            elif self.garden[j][i] == 'W':
                col_hits = 0 
            else:
                gardenScore[j][i] += col_hits 
    # print(gardenScore)

    # from top to bottom
    for i in range(len(self.garden[0])):
        col_hits = 0 
        for j in range(len(self.garden)-1, -1, -1):
            if self.garden[j][i] == 'F':
                col_hits += 1
            elif self.garden[j][i] == 'W':
                col_hits = 0 
            else:
                gardenScore[j][i] += col_hits 
                maxSeen = max(maxSeen, gardenScore[j][i])
    # print(gardenScore)

    for i in range(len(self.garden)):
        for j in range(len(self.garden[0])):
            if gardenScore[i][j] == maxSeen:
                self.garden[i][j] = "*"
    print(self.garden)
```

Comment: What is the justification for using DFS if your line of sight must be a straight line?

Comment: Perhaps I'm not using the term DFS properly. The line of sight is actually horizontally and vertically through the 2D array. That's why I use the first if statement in the dfs() method to search if the recursion will go out of bounds. My thinking is to essentially count all occurances of flowers (north, south, east and west from the current blank position) and then using another double for loop to retrieve the maximum and finally replace with an askterisk. Anyway easier?

Comment: Your algorithm would count a flower that is one unit to the left and one unit up from a person's location, even though that wouldn't be in their line of sight. That doesn't seem to be correct, if I'm reading the prompt correctly. Is my understanding correct, or did I misread the problem statement?

Comment: I think I need to spend more time on this :( Your understanding is correct. I'm getting confused by how my recursion calls drill down to check the north, south, east, and west line of sights to tally flower occurrences.

Comment: As a hint, use dynamic programming with four tables -- one for each cardinal direction. You can then find the answer by using a fifth table to combine the results from each of the four tables.

Comment: I should have thought about that! I'm going to try to make individual loops on lengths according to the position from each cardinal direction. I'll then try to get back to this recursive solution. Thanks :)!

Comment: https://leetcode.com/problems/bomb-enemy/

similar leetcode question

Comment: That problem requires LeetCode Premium; I can't see it. How much progress have you made on a DP solution?

Comment: I did the five individual loops you mentioned! It works now. I think DFS was never really an appropriate train of thought to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

#### Increase maximum recursion depth (Warning!)

> I'm getting stuck where python notes that my maximum recursion depth is being exceeded and haven't been able to progress with assigning an asterisk. Any thoughts?

##### Actually there is a way to increase the recursion limit in python.

By default maximum recursion limit in Python is 1000.
**Before explaining on how to increase the recursion limit**

#### Few things you should know !

- Without a recursion limit recursive function could call itself indefinitely. In other words, you could end up with an endless loop.
- Also, a stack overflow error can occur even if the recursion is not infinite. This can happen due to too big of a stack frame.
- In Python, the recursion limit takes these risks out of the equation.

#### I would not recommend increasing the recursion.

but rather try to implement your algorithm iteratively to avoid deep recursion.

#### Code to increase maximum recursion depth limit

```
import sys

#See current recursion limit by calling sys.getrecursionlimit()
print(sys.getrecursionlimit()) #(default = 1000)

print(sys.setrecursionlimit(2000)) # Sets the limit to 2000
```

Comment: Increasing the recursion limit will still produce a wrong answer; see the comments.